# Application Certificate Inavlid error from Quickbooks and VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, quickbooks

We are running QuickBooks Enterprise 7 (I know it is old and not supported). I have MS Access applications that are using the SDK (via VBA) to send transactions to QB. Nothing has change, but all of a sudden we are getting an error that the certificate for the application is invalid. We never had certificates before. It also did not pop up the window that lets me say I want it to run regardless of the certificate.

Anyone have any ideas what causes this? I have tried deleteing the application from QB and created a new one just to see what would happen but it still gives me the error.

My code looks like this:

```
Set QB = CreateObject("QBFC7.QBSessionManager")    
strDatabase = DLookup("Default_Company", "Configuration_table")
'get the qb file information
QB.OpenConnection "", "Upload Payroll"
QB.BeginSession strDatabase, omMultiUser
dblCredit = 0
Set JournalAddSet = QB.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 5, 0)
```

I really need help with this! Our company is dead in the water until I can get this going!

Comment: What year/version of MS Access are you running?  If you look at the certificates it was signed with does it have both SHA-1 and SHA-256?

Comment: We actually don't have certificates. We use the option from within Quickbooks that lets you run the application without one.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into the same problem with my interface from MS Access to QBooks via the SDK.

I believe it is caused by heightened security for Windows 10.  It happened to 2 of my customers yesterday.  I am going to upgrade the SDK dll from QBFC2.....dll to QBFC13....dll type libraries in VBA window Tools, References...and browse for the location, but also uncheck the old one QBFC...dll in the references.

You can download QBFC13 from Intuit website.

There are a few other things that may have to be done.  I had to do a replace all QBFC2 with QBFC13 when it calls libraries.  --->               ...,QBFC2Lib.... replace with ,,,,QBFC13Lib....

I compiled the VBA code and got another error message:

It was all the  request set messages had ...MSG... and I replaced it with ...IMSG...

Then the VBA compiled but I am waiting on my customer so I can test it on their PC with Windows 10 to see if it works.

Note 08/09/17 This did not fix the problem

However, My customer and I are both running Windows 8.1. She has MS Access 2016 and gets the Invalid certificate error when attempting to send an invoice to Qbooks using their SDK.

I brought her MS Access program back to me and sent the same invoice using the same version of QBooks SDK and did not get the error. I am running MS Access 2010.

Comment: I discovered that it was an update to Office 2016 that caused the certificate issues. The most recent update (I believe it is dated July 31) corrects the problem for me. I found that I didn't need QBFC13 (I use SDK7) when I upgraded to Windows 10 - I just had to redo the certificate acceptance within Quickbooks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was an update to Office 2016 that caused the certificate issues. The most recent update (Version 1707 dated July 31) corrects the problem for me. Not sure what was in either update (since I couldn't find a detailed description from Microsoft) that broke then fixed this issue.